# Limit circle/point of ODE with finite eigenvalues

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, sturm-liouville

Consider the following Sturm–Liouville (SL) eigenvalue problem $$(x^2y')'-[(x/2+a)^2+a]y=-\lambda^2y(x),$$ defined in $(-\infty,0]$ or $[0,\infty)$ or $(-\infty,+\infty)$ and parameter $a>0$. Therefore, the SL coefficient functions $p(x)=x^2$, $w(x)=1$, and $q(x)=-[(x/2+a)^2+a]$. It has a regular singularity $x=0$. We basically hope for homogeneous Dirichlet b.c.

It is solved by making the substitution $y(x)=e^{x/2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{(a+\frac{1}{2})^2-\lambda^2}}u(x)$, leading directly to the *Kummer's equation* $$xu''(x)+(\gamma-x)u'(x)-\alpha u(x)=0,$$ in which $\alpha=\sqrt{(a+\frac{1}{2})^2-\lambda^2}-a+\frac{1}{2}$ and $\gamma=1+2\sqrt{(a+\frac{1}{2})^2-\lambda^2}$. It has two (1st kind & 2nd kind) independent solutions. 
Let's then follow the standard argument.

Requiring nondivergence at $x=0$, the 2nd kind is dropped. Requiring nondivergence at infinity, the 1st kind is reduced to a polynomial when $-\alpha$ is a non-negative integer and eigenvalue $\lambda^2$ is attained.
Seen from this condition for $\alpha$, *we only have a bounded and finite sequence of eigenvalues*. Therefore, one probably also expects an additional continuous spectrum as suggested in the comments.

### Question

Is it possible to know the limit circle/point classification of this ODE near $0,\pm\infty$? Is the above solution useful for this purpose? How should one proceed? I also found page 13 of [this paper](http://www.math.niu.edu/SL2/papers/birk0.pdf) has a limit point/circle classification of the Kummer equation I used. Not sure if relevant.

Comment: Note that the standard Sturm–Liouville eigenvalue problem is linear in the eigenvalue. In your case that would be equivalent to also allowing imaginary $λ$.

Comment: @LutzL But actually assuming imaginary $\lambda$ doesn't really give any extra solution to the condition of $\alpha$. In any case, I can just use $\lambda$ instead and the question remains.

Comment: If there are only a finite number of eigenfunctions in $L^2$, then there must be continuous spectrum for the operator, provided you have properly defined endpoint conditions that lead to a well-posed selfadjoint problem.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Thanks. Yes, I think it is self-adjoint for homogeneous Dirichlet b.c. But a confusing thing is what if we consider this equation on (−∞,+∞) with homogeneous Dirichlet b.c.? The solution shown with $e^{x/2}$ doesn't seem to allow this at +∞. I'm not sure if this is normal. Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: $x=0$ is a singular point of your equation, which complicates any examination of the equation on $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Thank you. $\quad$ It seems that as long as the right boundary $x_R\geq 0$, the discrete spectrum remains the same although eigenfunction is only continuous and vanishing for $x\geq 0$, probably because of the singularity at $x=0$?  $\quad$ Although I understand it's possible, I've little experience on a complementary continuous spectrum. Does the continuous spectrum start from the largest eigenvalue? At which step shown in the question, it becomes invalid for solving the continuous spectrum? Could you shed some light? Thanks.

Comment: Are all of the solutions of the original equation in $L^2[0,\epsilon)$ for small $\epsilon$?

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Yes, they are, but diverge for large $\varepsilon$ due to the exponential. What I mean is we can solve the spectrum and eigenfunctions with homogeneous Dirichlet b.c. on $(-\infty,0)$ as shown. But for $(-\infty,x_R)$ with any positive $x_R$, the only solution I came up with is the same solution for $x\leq 0$ and constantly zero for $x>0$, which has same eigenvalues and is only continuous. And I don't know how to enter the continuous spectrum.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Sorry to bother you again. Do you think possible to know the limit circle/point classification of this ODE near $0,\pm\infty$? Is the solution shown useful? I also found page 13 of [this paper](http://www.math.niu.edu/SL2/papers/birk0.pdf) has a classification of the Kummer equation I used. Not sure if relevant.

Comment: @xiaohuamao : I had hoped to get time to look at this in more detail, but I'm not able. If all solutions are in $L^2(-\epsilon,0]$ then it's in the limit circle case at $0$. Similary at $-\infty$. That's going to take some time to check.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Thanks for your reply. This square integrability check of eigenfunctions should include only the discrete spectrum part or the whole mixed spectrum?

Comment: @xiaohuamao : Yes, sorry, that is a typo. Limit circle behaves as though you have a regular endpoint because you have two independent boundary functionals.

Comment: @xiaohuamao : I think this is beyond me to fully analyze. I'm curious where this equation came up. What do you expect for the spectrum?

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts This is a simplified version of a quantum mechanics problem I found. As is usually the case in elementary quantum mechanics textbooks (this is all that I was taught), I naively expected to find infinite discrete eigenvalues and eigenfunctions decaying at $\pm\infty$ (since $x$ is originally just a coordinate, not a radial variable). But the discrete spectrum turns out to be finite and eigenfunction is constantly zero when $x\geq0$. But there are various signs that the solution is useful and not wrong and sometimes models do introduce singularity no present in reality.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Then I noticed materials on singular SL problem and wanted to justify my solution and lay it on a sound mathematical foundation. Unfortunately, this seems somewhat beyond my very limited mathematical knowledge and ability. E.g., I have no idea how to enter the continuous spectrum and if it's real, although discrete part is much fun. And this asymmetry in eigenfunction between $\pm\infty$ and the singular $x=0$ as well makes me wonder about, if relevant, the limit circle/point classification of these three points. If only someone more experienced could help me through...